# Omitting the default/built-in fields of a feature class from getting listed

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I use `arcpy.ListFields()` method for various purposes and usually the only fields that I need are the ones added by the users. `ListFields` lists all fields including the ones comes in by default with any feature classes (e.g., OBJECTID, FID, Shape, SHAPE_Area, etc.), and I was wondering if there is an elegant way of omitting these fields from *listing*.

I can do, for example for GDB feature classes,

`[f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("sample_fc") if f.type not in ["OID","Geometry"] or f.name.upper() not in ["SHAPE_AREA", "SHAPE_Length"]]`

but this does not save me from getting "SHAPE_Area1" or other variants of inherited fields in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `required` property of the [Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm) object to make the difference between fields managed by ArcGIS (OID en shape fields), and fields added by the user:

```
[f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("sample_fc") if not f.required]
```

But if you (your geoprocessing workflow) make a copy of required fields (like 'SHAPE_Area**1**' seems to be), these copied fields won't be excluded from the list comprehension above (since they were added by the user).

What I use to do when my workflow adds inherited OID and shape fields from source datasets, is listing the fields I do need and deleting all the rest (except the required fields of course):

```
keep_fields = ["abc", "def"]
for f in arcpy.ListFields("sample_fc"):
  if not f.required:
    if not f.name in keep_fields:
      arcpy.DeleteField_management("sample_fc", f.name)
```